# Nginx Substitution module not getting called

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am very new to Nginx and writing module in Nginx. What I want is to manipulate the HTML body using Nginx module.

Now, there is already a Static module "ngx_http_subs_filter_module" present to substitute the string with another. For experiment I was using the same and see if it actually replace a string in the body of HTML. For some reason when ever I use the "subs_filter" it returns me an empty page.

Please note that I am not using localhost but instead I am using AWS server and hence using the IP address of that server to get Index.html page which go under the "location". My config file looks like:

```
location / 
{root html;
index index.html index.htm;
subs_filter_types text/html text/css text/xml;
subs_filter 'hello' 'HELLO' ir;
}
```

I am expecting that "hello" will be replaced with "HELLO" in the index.html.

Comment: Try using without the quote `subs_filter hello HELLO ir;` else it will search `'hello'` including the quotes

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that but the result is same.